# Binomial expansion of $(ax+b)^x$

Tags: probability

Could someone please help explain how to calculate $(ax+b)^x$ using the binomial expansion, where $x$ is some arbitrary constant?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by computing $(a+b)^n$, then see where you might go from there...

Comment: maybe I've used bad lettering? the exponent is just a constant. If it's easier, I could write it as (ak+b)^k, where k is just a constant

Comment: If $x$ is an integer, this is no problem to compute.  In fact, if $x$ is not an integer, we need only compute $(ax+b)^{x-[x]}(ax+b^{[x]}$...

Answer (score 3):

If we compute $(a+b)^n$, we have

$$a^n+na^{n-1}b+\binom n2a^{n-2}b^2+\dots+\binom n2a^2b^{n-2}+nab^{n-1}+b^n$$

With some simple substitutions ($a\to ax$, $n\to x$), we can get the desired result, with the assumption that $x$ is a non-negative integer.

If $x$ is a non-negative non-integer, then we must find a way to handle the non-integer part, $(ax+b)^{[x]}$.  The integer part, $(ax+b)^{x-[x]}$, can be handled as above.  The non-integer part could be calculated using a Taylor series.

If $x$ is negative, do the appropriate process above using $-x$ in the exponent slot, then use the result as the denominator in a fraction whose numerator is $1$.

If $x$ is not a real number (i.e., $x$ is complex or of some other non-real pedigree), none of the above will work correctly; probably best to take a complex analysis course to start with.

Comment: Haha good, simpler than mine :D I have the awesome (?) capacity of make things chaotic lol

Comment: Thank you ever so much @abiessu. You've been very helpful!

Comment: @philatwood: you're welcome, glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Calling $a\cdot x = X$ thence $x = \frac{X}{a}$

Your term becomes

$$\left(X + b\right)^{X/a}$$

you can now use the binomial of $(X + b)$ to the power $X' = X/a$